# Pass specific id to model and take data from database using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

My controller method like below

```
public function index($book_id) {

        print_r($book_id);

}
```

I will get the id from view. View like below

```
<a href="http://localhost/bookmooch/book/index/<?php echo $book->book_id; ?>"></a>
```

I need to get specific row according id on model how can I do that if I use query in controller its not working

If I use like below in controller it gives something else as result

```
public function index($book_id) {

        print_r($book_id);

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('books')->where('book_id', $book_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        print_r($query);
}
```

but if I use same query in model with hard coded id for testing it gives the expected out put

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include "/index" in anchor tag href as controller default method will be index if found. And "print_r($book_id)" should be "echo $book_id" as $book_id is variable not array.

Please try this code (either in model/controller):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('books', array('book_id' => $book_id));
$result = $query->row_array();
print_r($result);
```